# Select statement does not return full result because of white space between the words

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, razor, patindex

I have a select statement that's only returning a partial name and county because of white space.

The query should return: Stacey Cox but, it only returns Stacey.  It should also return Wayne County but, it returns Wayne.

I have tried using RegExp but, I get an error this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'RegExp' is not a recognized built-in function name.   I think it's because I'm using SQL Server.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT a.ID, UserName, Location 
FROM Location a, UserInfo b 
WHERE (b.Id) = (@0) AND (b.UserLocation) = (a.Id) and 
(RegExp(UserName, '\\s*\\w+(\\s\\w+)?\\s*'))
```

How can I get the query to return everything in the field?

Comment: there is no `regexp` in sql server

Comment: There is, however, `patindex`.

Comment: How do I use PatIndex to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search within a string, use [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) with wildcards:

```
WHERE UserName LIKE '%Stacey%'
```

Comment: What happens if I don't know the name?

Comment: Then I havn't understood your question. The error is caused by RegExp which does not exist in SQL Server. Remove that call and you should be ok.

Comment: I still need to get the data in the entire field.  It only gives me part of the name and not the full name or part of the county and not the entire county.  How can I get the entire name and county?

Comment: Check the SELECT part of the query - if you chose the correct fieldnames, everything will be returned. You may need to expand the columns in Sql Management Studio to make them wide enough, so you can see the whole result.

Comment: Nevermind I found the problem.  I didn't have quotes around my answer.  Once a added the quotes it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this homie, assuming that you are only looking for 'First Last' structure 
and also psql

SELECT a.ID, UserName, Location 
FROM Location a, UserInfo b 
WHERE (b.Id) = (@0) AND (b.UserLocation) = (a.Id) and 
(RegExp(UserName, '[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]][^[:space:]]+'))